# Отличие FETCH FIRST от FETCH OFFSET

Tags: sql, sql-server

Прочитал про наличие в sql server 2012 конструкции `OFFSET FETCH`, с помощью которой можно например более просто делать постраничную выборку в отличие от ROW_NUMBER. Я слышал, что можно использовать FETCH FIRST или FETCH NEXT. Попробовал поиграться с ними, но не увидел разницы, да и в источниках (в частности на msdn) этой разницы я так и не обнаружил. В чем же она? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А вы из какого языка обращаетесь к серверу? И какую технологию используете? Например, в языках под платформу .NET можно использовать LINQ, в котором постраничная выборка очень легко и красиво делается вызовом пары методов `.Skip().Take()`

Comment: @Yaant стоит запостить это как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188385(v=sql.110).aspx)

> FIRST и NEXT являются синонимами и предусмотрены для совместимости со
>   стандартом ANSI.

то есть никакой разницы между ними нет, можно использовать любой вариант.

Answer (score 3):

FETCH FIRST - показать только N первых строк (к примеру 25)

```
SELECT orderid, orderdate, custid, empid
FROM Sales.Orders
ORDER BY orderdate DESC, orderid DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 25 ROWS ONLY;
```

В конструкцие FETCH NEXT- пропустить 50 строк, и возвратить последующие, к примеру.

```
SELECT orderid, orderdate, custid, empid
FROM Sales.Orders
ORDER BY orderdate DESC, orderid DESC
OFFSET 50 ROWS;
```

А вот так по страницам можно сортировать:

```
DECLARE @pagesize AS BIGINT = 25, @pagenum AS BIGINT = 3;
SELECT orderid, orderdate, custid, empid
FROM Sales.Orders
ORDER BY orderdate DESC, orderid DESC
OFFSET (@pagenum - 1) * @pagesize ROWS FETCH NEXT @pagesize ROWS ONLY;
```

Подставляем @pagenum и попадаем на необходимую страницу относительно сортировке ORDER BY orderdate DESC, orderid DESC, с шагом 25 записей.

Comment: в вашем втором примере не используется FETCH NEXT. А меня именно интересует разница между FETCH FIRST и FETCH NEXT.  Если в вашем первом примере вместо FETCH FIRST написать FETCH NEXT то результат будет тем же самым. Так в чем разница?